# Add paged numbers on products posts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, pagination

So this is the website.. https://chicafriqfashion.com/ and one of the pages like https://chicafriqfashion.com/fabrics/ have products on the page.

I was able to add pagination at the bottom but it's just Prev and Next.

I need it to show page numbers.

Please help.

This is the start

```
<?php

        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'stock' => 1, 'product_cat' => 'earrings-ring', 'posts_per_page' => '12','order' => 'DESC', 'paged' => $paged );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
```

---

And this is my pagination code

```
<h3>Pages:  
<?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; PREV', $loop->max_num_pages) ?>
            <?php next_posts_link( 'NEXT &raquo;', $loop->max_num_pages) ?>
 </h3>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution -1 (Archive pages)

First fetch current page in to be passed in Wp_Query arguments.

```
        // current page
        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        // prepare arguments
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',
       'stock' => 1,
       'product_cat' => 'earrings-ring',
       'posts_per_page' => '12',
       'order' => 'DESC',
       'paged' => $paged 
       );

        //prepare query
        new WP_Query( $args );
```

You should call WordPress pagination function before wp_reset_postdata()

```
            the_posts_pagination( array(
                'prev_text'          => '<span class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>',
                'next_text'          => '<span class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>',
                'screen_reader_text' => '&nbsp;',
                'before_page_number' => '',
                'mid_size'    => 3,
            ) );
```

## Solution -2 (Custom Templates)

Construct Wp Query

```
        // prepare arguments
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',
       'stock' => 1,
       'product_cat' => 'earrings-ring',
       'posts_per_page' => '12',
       'order' => 'DESC',
       'paged' => $paged 
       );

        //prepare query
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $totalPage=$query->max_num_pages;
```

Call Pagination function

```
                $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                echo paginate_links( array(
                    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                    'total' => $totalPage
                ) );
```

This solution work for custom page templates. You can check wordpress official [documentation.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

Comment: I tried it but the pagination is not showing up...?

<?php

             // current page
        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        // prepare arguments
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',
       'stock' => 1,
       'product_cat' => 'earrings-ring',
       'posts_per_page' => '12',
       'order' => 'DESC',
       'paged' => $paged 
       );

        //prepare query
        
                     $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                     while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

Comment: <div align="center">
<?php 
   the_posts_pagination( array(
                'prev_text'          => '<span class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>',
                'next_text'          => '<span class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>',
                'screen_reader_text' => '&nbsp;',
                'before_page_number' => '',
                'mid_size'    => 3,
            ) ); ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

Comment: Are you using archive page or custom template to list all products?

Comment: I think this is a custom template. Another developer coded the website.

Comment: @Christine I have added another solution for custom template as well. I already using same function for custom templates.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your active theme `function.php` file.
**Note:** if you have child theme than add this code in child theme `function.php` file

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'number_pagination' ) ) :
    function number_pagination() {
        global $wp_query;

        $big = 999999999; 

        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
        ) );
    }
endif;
```

Add following code where you want to show number paggination.

```
<?php number_pagination( $loop ); ?>
</div>
```